# Jest mock gives undefined

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to do some tests, and it involves the auth part, using jwt. What I did try to do is importing the `jsonwebtoken` module, and after that mocking the decode and verify functions. What my problem is, that the returned value of the mock function will be undefined in the tested function.
In the api i am using the two functions which i am trying to mock and give me undefined.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
describe('test-api', () => {
  it('test endpoint 1', (finish) => {
    jwt.decode = jest.fn(() => { return {...} } )
    jwt.verify = jest.fn(() => { return {...} } )
    callApi();
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? Show the code under test